# EF4 - Linq - Exception on Query.Any()

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, invalidoperationexception

I've using EF for a while but I've never had this problem. Basically we have a WCF services that provide data for web front end. In that service, we use EF 4 as data implementation. Bypass all the repository and singleton, a simple Get function would be as below:

```
using (OurEntities DataContext = new OurEntities())
{
    DataContext.Order.MergeOption = System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking;
    List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
    var query = from p in DataContext.Order.Include("OrderDetail")
                where (p.OrderID == orderId || orderId == 0)
                   && (p.OrderStatus == orderStatus || orderStatus == 0)
                   && (p.OrderType == orderType || orderType == 0)
                   && (p.OrderFlag == null || p.OrderFlag == false)
                select p;

    if (query.Any())
    {
        foreach (Order order in query)
        {
            orders.Add(order);
        }
    }
    return orders;
}
```

orderId, orderStatus & orderType are passed in parameters.
The code works without any problems, as expected... until we run a few stress tests where we call the services (i.e. the GET functions) simultaneously from different clients. After a few minutes, we get a bunch of **InvalidOperationException: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Boolean' type is not valid**. In our SQL 2008 database, OrderID is int (identity, auto-gen) and OrderFlag is the only field with data type = bit (translated to boolean by EF). 
During debug, I found out that the exception was either thrown by query.Any() or by the foreach clause, when a single item in query is casted to Order. But if I touch the transaction by any mean (either run the same query on SSMS or execute query.Any() in the Watch window), query get updated with proper data and it just works....
Our evironment: VS 2010, .Net framework 4, EF 4, SQL Server 2008 express + standard (I've tried on both)
Any comments or any help would be greatly appreciated...
Eric

Comment: What is the whole meaning of `query.Any` except that you will execute it twice?

Comment: Firstly, it's recommended to use one DataContext per thread and not share them between thread. Is this the case in you case? (I'm guessing yes, but asking just in case). Secondly, as far as I understand this error can be produced by any property on Order *and* on OrderDetail. More over, there are potential wierdness when OrderDetail table does not have a record for correspondent Order record. Are there any booleans in OrderDetail class?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: yeah, query.Any does not make much sense here, but I believe it has nothing to do with OP's problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should start with modifying your code to:

```
using (OurEntities DataContext = new OurEntities())
{
    DataContext.Order.MergeOption = System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking;
    var query = from p in DataContext.Order.Include("OrderDetail")
                where (p.OrderID == orderId || orderId == 0)
                   && (p.OrderStatus == orderStatus || orderStatus == 0)
                   && (p.OrderType == orderType || orderType == 0)
                   && (p.OrderFlag == null || p.OrderFlag == false)
                select p;

    return query.ToList();
}
```

And run your tests again. I don't except that this will solve your problem but your current code is something that should not pass code review.

Comment: +1. Specifically since first calling .Any and then enumerating the query will result in _two_ db roundtrips.

Comment: Actually, it's our original code, but again, it failed at query.ToList().... That's why I want to check Any() before calling ToList(), just for the heck of it...